# something to with continuity and integration

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]→[0,1] $ be continuous then does $f$ assume the value $∫_0^1f^2(t)dt$ somewhere in $[0,1]$?

I don't know how to proceed in here.

Comment: Does $f^2$ mean $f$ multiplied by itself, or $f$ composed with itself?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: What if $f$ is constant? Do you see what happens if, say, $f$ only takes on some value strictly between $0$ and $1$?